# Macro to open excel hyperlinks

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2003

I would like to know if anyone can help me do a macro to open a list of hyper links.

I have a list of about 600 hyper links all in a column in separate rows, I have to open each one to see if the link works, yet it is boring and tedious as I have to wait sometimes for excel to catch up I would much rather leave it doing 100 at a time while I do other things

Comment: For whatever solution you find, there's a surprisingly odd feature in Office you might need to take into account: it first uses an Internet Explorer component (but is not identifying itself as Internet Explorer) to see if the URL one clicks is valid. After that, it hands *the resulting URL* to the default browser (or *not*, if the web site for some reason blocks the User Agent "Microsoft Office Existence Discovery"). Details at http://superuser.com/questions/41935/clicking-hyperlinks-in-email-messages-becomes-painfully-slow/42237#42237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub FollowLinks()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown))
        If c <> vbNullString Then
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (c.Offset(, 1).Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[Source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=65934)

Answer (score 0):

If you automate Internet Explorer, you may be able to print the browser
window from within Excel. You'll need to set a reference to Microsoft
Internet Controls.
Here's an example:

```
Sub printweb()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate Range("A1").Value 'A1 holds the URL

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    'This prints it
    ie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER

End Sub
```

[Source](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-971796.php)

Comment: This doesn't work, the range will be D237 to D337