# Excel automatic hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

After years of not wanting Word and Excel to automatically turn things into hyperlinks, the one time I want them to they refuse.

I have a list of strings in Excel which I am concatenating with a string to create a URL, I would like the resulting URL to be a clickable hyperlink but Excel won't play ball. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at Hyperlink worksheet function.

> Creates a shortcut or jump that opens
>   a document stored on a network server,
>   an intranet, or the
>   Internet. When you click the cell that
>   contains the HYPERLINK function,
>   Microsoft Excel opens the file stored
>   at link_location.
>
> Syntax
>
> `HYPERLINK(link_location,friendly_name)`

For example:

```
=HYPERLINK(B1, "Click for report")
```

Comment: When not using Internet Explorer as your default browser and you ever find some links that don't work as expected, then read about how Office uses "Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery" and the odd "User-Agent: Microsoft Office Existence Discovery" at http://superuser.com/questions/41935/clicking-hyperlinks-in-email-messages-becomes-painfully-slow/42237#42237