# Automatic hyperlink in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to hyperlink a url in excel automatically. I mean when the cell starts with something like http or www can I hyperlink that. Currently, I have to hit enter in the cell value in the formula bar to make the link as clickable. Also if I change the value in the cell, the link doesnt get refreshed until I hit enter. Is there a way in excel where it will automatically detect and apply a hyperlink.

Comment: I'm not sure if it meets your demand, but take a look at this one: http://superuser.com/questions/66130/excel-automatic-hyperlinks/66134#66134

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell what's being asked, but I've done my best to answer the question. Please let me know if that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: I think maybe @developer is talking about how you have to manually type it in. If I paste from another program a long list of urls, they do not auto-link.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting that automatically links manually-entered URLs. To activate it, do the following steps.

Open the *Excel Options* dialog by clicking on the *Office* button and selecting the *Excel Options* button.

[image: Open the Excel Options dialog]

In the *Excel Options* dialog, go to the *Proofing* section and click the *AutoCorrect Options* button.

[image: Click the AutoCorrect Options button]

In the *AutoCorrect* dialog, go to the *AutoFormat As You Type* tab and make sure "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks" is checked.

[image: Make sure 'Internet and network paths with hyperlinks' is checked]

Then you should be able to enter URLs as desired and they will be automatically turned into a hyperlink.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't worked!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a hyperlink in Excel with the `=HYPERLINK` formula.

1. Have the path / URL in a cell (Let's use A2 as an example)
2. use `=HYPERLINK(A2)` in another cell
3. Done!

The image below shows a (redacted) example of creating a Hyperlink (of a mapped drive) in column A with column C & B together.

[image]

Comment: This saved my day. It worked for me also with the value in the parenthes of the HYPELINK formula being another formula, in my case: =HYPERLINK(IF(FIND("http"; VideoLinks!B6; 1); VideoLinks!B6; "Check again later"))