# IE won't open Excel files

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, internet-explorer

I'm visiting a web site that is opening an Excel file in a new window.

From one PC (Windows XP, IE8, Office 2003), everything works. By works I mean that the new window appears, and I'm asked to open or save the .xls file. When I click Open, the file is opened in Excel in the new browser window.

From two other PC's ((Windows XP, IE7, Office 2003) & (Windows Vista, IE8, Office 2007)), I cannot access the file. The new browser window opens for about half a second and immediately closes. The Open/Save dialog is never shown.

All popup blockers have been disabled, I believe.

What setting is causing this?

**EDIT:**

More info:

I think the web site is streaming the content to the browser with the `ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel`. Opening excel files directly (clicking on hyperlink to xls file) works on every PC.

Opening up the same content in the new window as a PDF works on every PC. Acrobat is loaded in the new browser window and displays the content.

I have also cleared out my Temporary Internet Files directory, and the "Microsoft Office Control" IE add-on is enabled on every machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to tools/internet options/security/custom level and check if "Automatic prompting for file downloads" is disabled - it was for me with the exakt same symptoms!

Answer (score 0):

Are ActiveX controls allowed to run ? Check via `Internet Settings -> Security settings`

Answer (score 0):

If access to the file (or the whole web site) is protected by some user credentials, then *maybe* (though not *likely*, as you're using IE) this is [caused by Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery](https://superuser.com/questions/41935/clicking-hyperlinks-in-email-messages-becomes-painfully-slow/42237#42237).