# Make Excel 2007 open hyperlinks in Firefox

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, browser, microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007, when I click a hyperlink, it opens in IE.
I'm running XP Professional SP3.

Firefox is set as my default browser. Links in Word and Outlook open in Firefox. But Excel opens them in IE. Anyone know how to fix it?

**Edit:**
Process Explorer shows the command line for IE to be

`"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" -Embedding`

Comment: Fix it? It's not really broken.

Comment: How is it not broken? It's opening links in a browser other than my default browser. Thanks so much for the helpful comment.

Comment: Not a direct answer, and not very likely, but it *might* be somehow related to "Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery" See http://superuser.com/questions/41935/clicking-hyperlinks-in-email-messages-becomes-painfully-slow/42237#42237

Comment: And though I doubt it matters: are these hyperlinks created using the `HYPERLINK` formula, or links that are made clickable automatically just because Office recognises them?

Comment: Using HYPERLINK formula or Developer Toolbar-> Insert Hyperlink.
I tried pasting text that contained a hyperlink and Excel didn't linkify it.

I will look into DDE when I get a chance to see if it leads anywhere. Thanks for the link!

Comment: BTW the fact that you asked me that question gives you instant +100 superuser credibility!

Answer (score 1):

I just checked here with my Excel 2007, Firefox, and Windows XP Pro SP3, and Excel opened a link in Firefox, which is my default browser.

I would try "resetting" your default browser in the system by setting the default to IE and back to Firefox.

In Internet Explorer:

- Go to "Tools" and then "Internet Options"
- Click on the "Programs" tab
- Click the "Make default" button
- Click OK

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the `Run` box, and type in a website (ie, www.google.com). It should open in Internet Explorer.

In Firefox:

- Go to "Tools" and then "Options"
- Click on the "Advanced" tab (on the far right)
- Click on the "General" tab
- Click the "Check Now" button

  - If Firefox is not the default browser, which it shouldn't be right now, it should ask if you want to set Firefox as your default browser. Click Yes

Go back to the `Run` box (or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again) and type in a website (ie, www.google.com). This time, it should open in Firefox.

Check Excel and see if it's opening it in the right browser now.

Comment: Nope, still happening. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: And thanks for letting me know it works for you. Now at least I know that it's possible for it to work correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Three fairly easy solutions here:
http://www.consumingexperience.com/2008/02/make-links-in-word-excel-etc-open-in.html

Comment: Mike, thanks for contributing, but in Superuser we like people to summarize solutions, not just link them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method, it launch link in default browser:

> Dim something as link
>
> ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink link