# How to load a Html Image with https in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, html, ssl

I have an image that is like

```
https://example.company.org/image
```

When I type this into the browser it says

> The site's security certificate is not trusted!

and then I  proceed saying "OK" - it loads up fine .  .

To `wget` this I can do

```
wget https://example.company.org/image --no-check-certificate
```

However the problem is that I want this to open up in MS Word (I.e a scenario where the Clipboard (In HTML Format) is copied into MS Word) . How can I bypass this security ?
How to make SSL word with MSWord or how do I remove this security altogether for a particular URL only ?

Comment: Have you tried it with simply "http://example.company.org/image" ? I mean, HTTP instead of HTTPS ?

Comment: That is giving the same result - I think some sites default to HTTPS in the server side ?

Comment: Looks like we have a similar issue reported http://superuser.com/questions/261415/dynamic-images-served-over-https-display-broken-image-in-word-when-opening-an-ht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested , Server should get a certificate that is valid with a CA bundled with Windows - so that Windows recognizes the https://  That is , the scenario where IE doesn't prompt you for a Security Certificate or doesn't show you the Security Warning in Address bar scenario it will work fine !

Comment: Indeed. One can manually add root certificates to the trust list, if desired. Dunno about self-signed certificates though.